# C# variable in a MySql query isn't recognized

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2017, query-string

I have an int variable in my C# code and I'm trying to use it in a MySql query.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace projeV1
{

    public partial class ProjeDetay : Form
    {

        public ProjeDetay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ProjeDetay_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int satir_projem = Projeler.satir_proje;
            string connectionString = "Server = localhost; Port = ...; Database = ...; Uid = root; Pwd = ...; Allow User Variables=True";
            MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlCommand command;

            databaseConnection.Open();
            command = databaseConnection.CreateCommand();

            string myQuery = "select projeAdi from projeler where projeID = @satir_projem";
            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(myQuery, databaseConnection);
            command.Parameters.Add("@satir_projem", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = satir_projem;

            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(DS);
            dataGridView_ProjeDetay.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];

            MessageBox.Show(Projeler.satir_proje.ToString());

            MessageBox.Show(satir_projem.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

(Sorry if it looks like a mess in regard to coding but I'm new at this ^^)

MessageBox windows show the variables' values correctly, so there's no problem with the variable. And when I replace`@satir_projem` from the query string with a number like "2" (see the example below), for example, the result is correct, but when I use @satir_projem in the query, it doesn't work. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Example query string:

```
"select projeAdi from projeler where projeID = 2"
```

P.S 1: Originally I'm trying to get the index of the selected row (which is the variable called Projeler.satir_proje) in a DataGridView used in a form called "Projeler" and in another form (which is called ProjeDetay), assigning that index value into another variable called "satir_projem" and use this value to get the related data from my database and put that data in another DataGridView located in my second form (which is called dataGridView_ProjeDetay).

P.S 2: I've made a lot of research about this problem and tried many of the solutions I encountered along the way; however, none of them worked for me. So, here I am :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@satir_projem", satir_projem);` ?

Comment: Yes, I did try that, but it didn't work back then, but thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting parameter for command that is not used.
Instead you should use `DataAdapter.SelectCommand`

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlCommand command;

string myQuery = "select projeAdi from projeler where projeID = @satir_projem";

databaseConnection.Open();

command = new MySqlCommand(myQuery, databaseConnection);

MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Just want to elaborate, why @Onur_Saatcioglu's code is throwing error.

you are adding @satir_projem to command but the parameter thus added to command is not being passed to dataadapter which serves as a bridge between a DataSet and SQL Server for retrieving and saving data.

Hence you can

1) As Lester told, create command like

```
command = new MySqlCommand(myQuery, databaseConnection);
```

and pass the command to DataAdapter

```
MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
```

2) As @Pablo_notPicasso said, if you are using

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@satir_projem", satir_projem);
```

then "command"  does not make sense, you can just delete it.